# React - automatic submission of form upon changing input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to submit a form automatically in React with the `onChange` event. It works for regular `input` fields, but it somehow doesn't work with [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select). Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MarbilleJuntado/447e6e839253d5945f2992f38d7b3f29) of my React component.

I'm specifically trying to update the `startDate` and `endDate` attributes. I'm also getting this warning: `EducationForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled`. I suspect it's because `startDate` and `endDate` don't have initial values, so I added this in the constructor:

```
this.state.attributes.startDate = ''
this.state.attributes.endDate = ''
```

However, I am still getting the same warning despite that. This is my attempt to submit the form with the `onChange` event of the `Select` tags:

```
<Select
  className='form-control'
  name='startDate'
  value={attributes.startDate}
  required={true}
  onChange={e => {
    this.updateAttribute(e, 'startDate')
  }}
  options={this.options}
/>

<Select
  className='form-control'
  name='endDate'
  value={attributes.endDate}
  required={true}
  onChange={e => {
    this.updateAttribute(e, 'endDate')
  }}
  options={this.options}
/>
```

`updateAttribute` calls the `submitForm` method:

```
updateAttribute = (e: ReactEvent, attribute: string) => {
  e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault()

  const attributes = {
    ...this.state.attributes,
    [attribute]: e.target ? e.target.value : e
  }
  this.setState({ attributes: attributes }, () => this.submitForm())
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your code immediately prior is, but is it possible that `attributes.startDate` should be `this.state.attributes.startDate`?

Comment: @JordanS I updated the description. `startDate` and `endDate` both call the same function `updateAttribute` to handle the change of input and to submit the form. You can check the whole code in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/MarbilleJuntado/447e6e839253d5945f2992f38d7b3f29) I linked.

Comment: Right, but in your select JSX you are setting the value to `attributes.startDate`, do you have `let attributes = this.state.attributes` somewhere prior, or did you mean to set the value to `this.state.attributes.startDate`?

Comment: @JordanS In line 139, I have this statement: `const attributes = this.state.attributes`.

Comment: `const attributes = this.state.attributes` should be `const {attributes} = this.state`

Comment: @Manoz i'll look into that. Btw, i think the form is not submitting since `startDate` and `endDate` need to be validated as strings, but since react-select `options` need to be an array of objects, the input saved is also an object of the format `{value: '2018', label: '2018'}`. Is there any way to capture the input as a string like '2018' instead of the entire object?

Comment: You can parse it with `moment`. like `moment(dateObject).format("YYYY")`. that will get you value as string.

Comment: @Manoz but that will still save the input as an object, and I can't make react-select's options an array of strings since the docs say it has to be an array of objects.

Comment: did you manage log `startDate, endDate` ? do you see any value with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176536/discussion-between-bargain23-and-manoz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in your `onChange` handler. React-Select has a very specific signature for `onChange`

```
function (
  One of <
    Object,
    Array<Object>,
    null,
    undefined
  >,
  {
    action required One of <
      "select-option",
      "deselect-option",
      "remove-value",
      "pop-value",
      "set-value",
      "clear",
      "create-option"
    >
  }
  ) => undefined
```

Yes, most find this confusing. Your `onChange` attribute then becomes something more like this:

`onChange={(value, {action}) => this.updateValue(value, action)}`

Your `updateValue` method then acts on your select's value change according to the type of action which was taken. A React-Select in single select will give you a `value` Object of the selected `option` (the entire object that made up that `option`). A React-Select in multi select will give you an Array of Objects as the `value`. Your `value` type is different, depending on whether it is single or multi select, and the `action` taken.

What you do with your `value` is up to you, at this point. Take that `value`, apply the appropriate key(s) to your data object you're POSTing, and call whatever method you want to save your data.